# How do you drop all "£" and "," in all the columns at once, not one at a time?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, lambda

Need to remove all "£" and "," from an excel file in my jupyter notebook using python. I know how to do 1 column at a time but there are many columns and I want to drop all the "£" and "," at once and resave it.

I have tried a bunch of different things from here but they are only showing a list or one column at a time I need to drop all the "£" and "," at once as it is too time consuming.

```
df.head()

total           refunded    tax
£43,622.61  £4,528.86   £16,975.51
£133,873.05 £37,093.26  £3,561.38
£19,253.19  £14,253.07  £2,544.06
£153,947.84 £11,993.01  £2,779.59
£227,844.55 £29,682.94  £52,195.53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way `replace`

```
df=df.replace({'£':'',',':''},regex=True)
df
       total  refunded       tax
0   43622.61   4528.86  16975.51
1  133873.05  37093.26   3561.38
2   19253.19  14253.07   2544.06
3  153947.84  11993.01   2779.59
4  227844.55  29682.94  52195.53
```

Comment: I tried `replace` first and it didn't work but now I see that one must use `regex=True`. TIL

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method to apply a function to all columns of a `pandas` dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = io.StringIO("""
total refunded tax
£43,622.61 £4,528.86 £16,975.51
£133,873.05 £37,093.26 £3,561.38
£19,253.19 £14,253.07 £2,544.06
£153,947.84 £11,993.01 £2,779.59
£227,844.55 £29,682.94 £52,195.53
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=' ')

def cleaner(x):
    cleaned = [''.join([c for c in s if c not in {'£', ','}]) for s in x]
    return cleaned

df = df.apply(cleaner)

print(df.to_string())

#        total  refunded       tax
# 0   43622.61   4528.86  16975.51
# 1  133873.05  37093.26   3561.38
# 2   19253.19  14253.07   2544.06
# 3  153947.84  11993.01   2779.59
# 4  227844.55  29682.94  52195.53
```